# If a series is conditionally convergent, is it useless?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So in math, analysis in particular, divergent series are not particularly interesting since most sequences are divergent. However convergent series are interesting and they are useful. However, mathematicians have realized they had to be careful and define two types of convergence. Most of the theorems rely on absolute convergence.

Therefore my question is, if your series turns out to be conditionally convergent, are you stuck? That is, can you not conclude anything further or can you still work with a conditionally convergent series?

Comment: It is certainly *less* useful, for sure. But, it's still a convergent series, meaning you can still use it to approximate its limit. You can still compute partial sums of $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \cdots$ to approximate $\log 2$ (albeit with very slow convergence).

Comment: It can be very useful in some situations, see Abel's theorem for example.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah... but are conditionally convergent series really useful for Abel's theorem, or is Abel's theorem more useful for dealing with conditionally convergent series? :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit I am not Abel to answer that.

Comment: "divergent series are not particularly interesting" [Hardy](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/divergent-series_gh-hardy/3094305/item/58411114/), [Balser](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0073564), and [Mitschi & Sauzin](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-28736-2) might beg to differ... But, to your question: what makes a series "useful" to you? Conditionally convergent series are certainly useless for e.g. the comparison test, although so are absolutely convergent series that happen to be non-positive. But a Fourier series might well be conditional; the square wave is, IIRC.